# How to instantiate a FIFO on an iCE40 FPGA?

Tags: fpga, fifo

The Memory Usage Guide for the Lattice iCE40 FPGAs implies that the embedded block RAM can be configured in various ways, including as a FIFO, but it gives no details about how to do this.

Is there another document which describes this, or do they mean that a FIFO could be made using an EBR?

Comment: As far as I am aware every FPGA vendor has a library or IP generator for memories and FIFOs. p.s. do not assume everybody knows your abbreviations. I don't know what 'EBR' stands for, maybe a Lattice specific term?

Comment: Does the [documentation](http://www.clifford.at/icestorm/ram_tile.html) that project icestorm reverse-engineered help? I'd say the memory usage guide implies that logic to handle read and write pointers to build a FIFO is used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Memory Usage Guide for ice40 devices states:

> Using programmable logic resources, an EBR implements a [...]
>   First-In, First-Out (FIFO) memory.

The ice40 series doesn't have any hard FIFO blocks, you have to add the necessary logic around the memory blocks (EBR).

In Lattice Radiant software there is a "IP Block Wizard" that allows you to get some pre-written code for FIFOs. In Lattice icecube2 there doesn't seem to be a IP core generator included.

On the other hand, writing a simple FIFO in a single clock domain is a nice exercise and can be done in a few dozen lines of code.